# Is there an accounting or ERP package that runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac?

Tags: cross-platform, accounting, erp

Is there an accounting or ERP package, either closed- or open-source, that has clients that run on Windows, Linux, and Mac?

- It does not matter if it is a free or paid solution.
- It must also be a "thick client" solution, not something that runs in a web browser (there is a specific business reason for this so it's not negotiable).  If you provide a product/solution that runs in a browser, I will at least give you a point in recognition but I won't be able to accept it as an answer.
- Solutions that provide source code are given special consideration and will be more likely to receive the accepted answer, as this is for a highly-dynamic business environment, where requirements are changing weekly, or even daily.

Clarification: the idea is that, whatever the package is, you would be able to migrate between platforms (or use all three, if needed) and not worry about migrating your accounting/ERP.  The point about web browsers is a deal-breaker, please don't bug me about how it would be "easier" as this is someone else's requirements, so it's not something I can control.  Source code is a very important factor as a canned package would not be expected to live long in this environment.

Comment: I'm going to leave this open for another week or so, to see if I can find a few more solutions out there.  Thanks so far to everyone who's chipped in.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Could you explain why a browser solution is out? What specific business reason is there for requiring a thick client?

Comment: The reason? /Because the boss says so./ :(

Comment: I don't think that counts as a "specific business reason" :-).

Comment: When the boss signs the check, then as far as you are concerned, it's a specific business reason. :(  But I hear you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiere may well tick a number of your boxes, given that it is Open Source, has a client written in Java, so should run on all the platforms you listed, and is an ERP/accounting system.

- [Compiere Sourceforge Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/compiere/)
- [Compiere Home Page](http://www.compiere.com/)

I will say I've not personally used the system, but I did look at it around 6-7 years ago, when my then employer was looking for an accounting system for an overseas subsidiary they were setting up. It was definitely the best of the (free) bunch back then, just overkill for our needs!

Answer (score 3):

There are ERP systems like [SAP](http://www.sap.com/solutions/business-suite/erp/index.epx) that support a web client/service-oriented architecture.  Not even close to free, but you did not specify that.

EDIT: After my answer was posted you specified that it not involve a browser interface.  Your enterprise can set its own rules, but I think it's worth emphasizing (since SU is about sharing answers, not just solving your problem) that thin-client solutions are used in many highly-secure environments, with access verifiably restricted to within a network.  The SAP system I mentioned has many highly-secure installations.

Comment: +1 for a perfectly legit mechanism.  I'm sorry about the follow-up edit, I just realized I had forgotten this requirement.  I agree that it's 100% silly, but sometimes, other people make the rules, and they have their own notion of why something is or isn't acceptable.  So, that's why in the re-edit I said I would still give a point - because I believe, like you, that the idea has merit.  If I could award more points, I would.  I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Not a problem - I hope my words did not cause you to infer I was irritated - I was just explaining the sequence of events to those arriving late, so it would all make sense. I found your question to be worth answering, and your edits worthy of response - all good. I certainly commiserate with having to deal with decision-makers who don't always listen to reason and data - it's the way of the world.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I'd mention [Phasis](http://www.phasis.it/), a multi-platform open source ERP written in wxPython, by a team of italian volunteers :)

Comment: tempting, but can you re-edit and mention if it runs on all three platforms?

Comment: bah, took the time to go to the site, and while I can't speak Italian, I was able to figure out that it will run on all 3 platforms, so +1 for you. :)

Comment: Well I'll re-edit it anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

We're currently implementing [OpenERP](http://openerp.com/) and we have it running on Windows and GNU/Linux. It's a bit clunky, but if you're a small to medium-sized business, it's worth a look. The download page has this to say about running on Mac:

> Currently, there is no official [native] version of OpenERP for Mac systems.
>
> However, you may want to have a look at [the blog of Taktik](http://devteam.taktik.be), an official belgian OpenERP partner, who builds a Mac version of the OpenERP GTK client. They also provide step-by-step instructions on installing the OpenERP Server on a Mac.

I wouldn't recommend OpenERP unless you have some developers on staff who are willing to learn to read Python code. The documentation is sometimes incomplete or outdated, so being able to check what the code is doing makes it easier to figure out how to use the system. Setting up a development system that lets you step through the code in debug mode is also really helpful.